# How do I login silently to multiple web applications without user being interrupted to keep their sessions active

Tags: authentication, java, .net

We need to login to 20 - 30 different web applications and enter credentials to keep user active throughout the day. This needs to happen in the background on user's machine without user being interrupted. What technology do we use here to achieve this?

We thought of using an RPA but this is intrusive and causes user interruption. User will be locked out of using their machine while RPA is running.

We expect this automated code to login to multiple web application one at a time or in a parallel thread (no preference) throughout the day on a schedule or user can kick this off. This automated solution needs to be able to hold user credentials and keep user free from entering their credentials.

Can we use C#, vbscript, java or any other software development tool to achieve this type of effort?

We'd like to keep this in-house to keep cost low.

Comment: @mentallurg Comments on SO recommended me post here. Hence, on SE.

Comment: Describe your login types, what exactly is used for authentication.

Comment: Is involving a browser required? If these web apps have APIs, can't you build an aggregator for the  events/data/$THINGS from all these apps?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue We'll have to investigate to see if they have APIs.

Comment: @mentallurg All websites are external. User enters userid and password to login to each website. Sessions expire anywhere between 15 min - 60 min. We want to be able to run a script in the background to keep their sessions alive.